# Dual Riemannian metric and the Dual Metric Form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Rieamnnian manifold with metric $g: X(M) \times X(M) \to C^{\infty}(X)$, where $X(M)$ are the vector fields of $X$.

As is well known, we can induce a bilinear pairing 
$$
\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_g: \Omega^1(M) \times \Omega^1(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)
$$
by setting 
$$
\langle \omega, \omega' \rangle_g = g(\omega^{\sharp}, (\omega')^{\sharp}),
$$
where, as usual, $\sharp$ is defined by $g(\omega^\sharp, X) = \omega(X)$, for $X \in X(M)$.

On the other hand, as is also well known, there exists a unique element $\omega_g \in \Omega(M) \otimes \Omega(M)$ such that, for $(X,Y) \in X(M) \times X(M)$, 
$$
\omega_g (X,Y) = g(X,Y),
$$ 
where $\omega_g$ is applied to $(X,Y)$ in the obvious way.

Thus, we have a pairing on $T^\ast(M)$ and an element of $\Omega(M) \times \Omega(M)$ both coming from $g$. I would like to know if there exists a simple relationship between these two objects. (By simple, I suppose I mean something global and algebraic, free from messy local expressions.)

Moreover, what does metric compatibility for a connection look like for either of these?

Comment: What is the "action" of $g$ on $T(M) \times T(M)$? If you just mean applying $g$ to two vector fields, in what sense is this an action?

Comment: @Spiro: I've edited according to your comment. Is this better?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Both Deane and Dick are correct, though, this is linear algebra. Everything here is defined pointwise and is tensorial. When you understand what is happening at a point, you understand what's happening on the whole manifold. These two objects are exactly the same thing, as long as you view the space of symmetric bilinear forms on $V$ as a subspace of $V^* \otimes V^*$.

Comment: @Spiro I understand that the question is determined by the pointwise data, but I am interested in whether it can be expressed as some thing global. For example, take vector fields which have a pointwise construction using tangent spaces, and a much nicer global one which describes them as derivations.

Comment: Perhaps the notion of a Riemann manifold overly general for your purposes?  If should happen that the problem(s) you have in mind admit a K&auml;hlerian complex structure, then the (vanishing) [Nijenhuis tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Integrable_almost_complex_structures) might provide the natural, "non-messy" global structure that you are seeking.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in K\"ahler structures as it happens, thanks for the reference.

Comment: That's good to know ... I will expand my comment into an answer.

Comment: I'm an old-fashioned differential geometer, so I don't understand all of this. Any chance you could explain how you define a Riemannian or Kahler metric as "something global and algebraic, free from messy local expressions"?

Comment: @Deane: Pretty much as I stated in the question. I quate here from "Elements of Non-commutative Geometry" Varilly et al: A *Riemannian metric* on a manifold $M$ is a positive definite pairing on smooth vector fields, ie, $g:X(M) \times X(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$, which is $C^{\infty}(M)$-bilinear and satisfies $g(X,X) > 0$, for any non-zero $X \in X(M)$. 

For a Kahler metric I'm not so sure, but it would be something in the same spirit.

Comment: (I expect I'm missing something, but here goes nothing).  I think that this can be made formal simply by "doing" linear algebra over the ring $C^\infty(M)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.  Of course, things are a little trickier with working over a ring instead of a field, but it's still quite a nice ring so a lot still carries over.  You need to use the correct tensor product, but then you get the adjunction $Hom(X(M), Hom(X(M),C^\infty(M))) \cong Hom(X(M) \otimes X(M),C^\infty(M))$ for purely algebraic reasons.  Using this tensor product, I think it all goes through formally.

Answer (score 6):

It is worth noting that this is really a question in linear algebra. An inner product on a vector space $V$ defines an element in $ \omega \in V^*\otimes V^ * $. The same inner product also induces an inner product on $V^* $.  How is the inner product on $V^* $ related to $\omega$? It is, I suppose, a reasonable question, but you should be able to figure it all out using a basis of $V$, the dual basis of $V^*$, and the matrices representing the inner products as well as the tensor $\omega$.

[ADDED] As for the relationship between $\omega_g$ and the inner product on the cotangent bundle, isn't it the same as the relationship you give between $g^*$ and the inner product on the tangent bundle? In other words
$$
\omega_g(\theta^\sharp, \phi^\sharp) = g^*(\theta, \phi)
$$

Comment: Yes of course we can do this for a vector space. The trouble is that that the vector space structure of $T(X)$ is infinte dimensional and doesn't admit any managable basis. It's only its module structure that is managable. One can of course look at everything locally, but this is messy. What I asked for in the question was a global solution to the problem. 

Comment: It is not really an infinite dimensional question, and it is a "pointwise" and not a local question about the manifold since everything is happening fiber by fiber. Thus, as Deane says, it IS a finite dimensional vector space question.

Comment: Fair enough for the distinction between pointwise and local - so to rephrase - Is there a global way to do it that is neither pointwise nor local, in other words, can we do this using the global module structure, not the pointwise vector space structure.

Comment: @John: I cannot understand why you would WANT to use a "global" method other than the obvious one that applies the pointwise identification fiber by fiber.

Comment: Why I would want to do this is because I'm thinking about something in noncommutative geometry where the local no-longer exists. Maybe I should have explained this in the question, I was trying to express the question without mentioning ncg so as it would be of interest to a wider audience.

Comment: But if you are thinking about global objects, then your inner product takes values in $C^\infty(M)$ and not $\mathbb{R}$, right? If that's the case, I think you need to rewrite your question completely, because then I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I've reworded the question - sorry the confusion.

Comment: Yes, Deane is correct. These two objects are the same.

Answer (score 2):

What comes to my mind is a co-algebra structure, however, I'm not sure if it is of big importance. The coproduct $\Delta: T^\ast (M)\to T^\ast (M)\otimes T^\ast (M)$ is a homeomorhpism which preserves the inner product.

Comment: [This is off-topic of course, but I can't resist] The (shuffle) coalgebra structure is indeed of big importance, but nobody seems to notice. Consider the "total" covariant derivative iterated to the k-th total covariant derivative. Apply this to a tensor product. In classical tensor calulus this gives a huge mess. But using the comultiplication you get a nice and short generalization of the general Leibniz product rule (except the binomial coefficients are now hidden in the comultiplication). Simplest nontrivial application: Curvature is a tensor.

Comment: You have made me curious: what coalgebra structure is there on $T^*M$? I would expect it to be dual to some algebra structure on $TM$, but I cannot think of any such structure right now.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, the notion of a Riemann manifold is overly general.  If should happen that the problem(s) one has in mind admit a Kählerian complex structure, then the vanishing of the [Nijenhuis tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Integrable_almost_complex_structures)—which expresses an integrability condition—can provide the "non-messy" global structure that is requested.  Associated to the vanishing Nijenhuis tensor is a closed symplectic form that in dynamical models usefully specifies [Hamiltonian vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you be a little more specific on why it provides the required global structure please?

Comment: Like several other posters, the requested answer that is "global and algebraic, free from messy local expressions" is a bit hazy. It was just a guess on my part, that no matter what nice structures you have  in mind, the Kahlerian compatible triple (that is, the compatible metric, symplectic, and complex structures) and/or the Hamiltonian flows thereby associated to smooth functions, will be helpful in constructing them. Further reading in (e.g.) Moroianu's "Lectures on Kahler Geometry" and Flaherty's (older) "Hermitian and Kahlerian Geometry in Relativity" might be helpful too.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I'll have a look at those references.

Comment: The original question has nothing to do with complex or Kahler structures.  This answer seems non-responsive.